# How do I interrupt a background thread that's blocking on IO?

Tags: c, pthreads, interrupt

I have a C program with two threads: the main thread continously reads data from the network and prints it out to the screen, while the secondary thread listens for and handles keypresses from standard input.

Currently my program catches SIGINT, SIGTERM, and SIGPIPE in order to terminate the program cleanly. My problem is that at the end of the main thread (once the main loop has terminated from the signal handler), it attempts to revert the terminal settings using `tcsetattr`, however this blocks until the current `fgetc` call on the other thread returns.

How can I interrupt the background thread so that the `fgetc` call returns and the main thread can restore the terminal settings and exit cleanly?

I have tried using `pthread_kill(thread, SIGINT)` but that just causes my existing signal handler to be called again.

Relevant code:

```
// If the program should still be running.
static sig_atomic_t running = 1;

// Background thread that reads keypresses.
pthread_t thread;

static void *get_keypresses();

static void receive_signal(int signal) {
    (void)signal;
    running = 0;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    // Set up signal handling.
    if(signal(SIGINT, receive_signal) == SIG_ERR) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error setting signal handler for SIGINT.\n");
    }
    if(signal(SIGTERM, receive_signal) == SIG_ERR) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error setting signal handler for SIGTERM.\n");
    }
    if(signal(SIGPIPE, receive_signal) == SIG_ERR) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error setting signal handler for SIGPIPE.\n");
    }

    // Set up thread attributes.
    pthread_attr_t thread_attrs;
    if(pthread_attr_init(&thread_attrs) != 0) {
        perror("Unable to create thread attributes");
        exit(2);
    }
    if(pthread_attr_setdetachstate(&thread_attrs, PTHREAD_CREATE_DETACHED) != 0) {
        perror("Unable to set thread attributes");
        exit(2);
    }

    // Set up terminal for reading keypresses.
    struct termios orig_term_attr;
    struct termios new_term_attr;
    tcgetattr(fileno(stdin), &orig_term_attr);
    memcpy(&new_term_attr, &orig_term_attr, sizeof(struct termios));
    new_term_attr.c_lflag &= ~(ECHO|ICANON);
    tcsetattr(fileno(stdin), TCSANOW, &new_term_attr);

    // Start background thread to read keypresses.
    if((pthread_create(&thread, &thread_attrs, &get_keypresses, NULL)) != 0) {
        perror("Unable to create thread");
        exit(2);
    }

    // Main loop.
    while(running) {
        // Read data from network and output to screen.
    }

    // Restore original terminal attributes. ***IT BLOCKS HERE***
    tcsetattr(fileno(stdin), TCSANOW, &orig_term_attr);

    return 0;
}

// Get input from the keyboard.
static void *get_keypresses() {
    int c;
    while(running) {
        // Get keypress. ***NEEDS TO BE INTERRUPTED HERE***
        if((c = fgetc(stdin)) != - 1) {
            // Handle keypress.
        }
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

Comment: There is a post here that describes a method that you can use to interrupt. This can be used in conjunction with a flag or similar set by something such as what @HapKom has suggested. Also suggest using a Sleep(); after you have completed the action within your thread worker function, eg. right under your `// Handle keypress` comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace

```
if((c = fgetc(stdin)) != -1)
```

with

```
if (0 < read(fileno(stdin), &c, 1))
```

`read()` would be interupted if the thread received a signal.

Answer (score 4):

There are two ways to go:

- you change your code not to block (using O_NONBLOCK, poll(), select(), etc.),
- you force your blocked code to get kicked out of the blocking system call.

Forcing the end of a system call can basically be done in two ways: either you make the system call impossible to finish (for example, you close the file descriptor the blocking call waits on), or you send some signal to that thread, and make sure that the signal handling is properly set up. The proper signal handling means that the signal is not ignored, not masked, and that the signal flags are set up in such a way that the system call does not get restarted after the signal handling (see sigaction(), SA_RESTART flag).

Answer (score 2):

I managed to find a solution that works well for me: I made reading from standard input non-blocking.

```
fcntl(fileno(stdin), F_SETFL, O_NONBLOCK);
```

This also requires some form of `sleep` (or `usleep` or `nanosleep`) in the background thread.

Thanks for HapKoM for getting me thinking in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

One way that I see is to read stdin by **poll()** or **select()** with some small timeout. And when it returns on timeout you can check "running" flag and perform clear termination if it is set to "false" value.

May be it is not the best solution, but it should work.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't use those methods, but this prompted me to think about making the `fgetc` call non-blocking and then I hit the solution.